# I want to add a checkbox to a table I'm showing on my website from by database

Tags: mysql, html, twitter-bootstrap, phpmyadmin

I am displaying a table from my database. I want to add a check box to to the rows so that I can select any rows that I want and perform an action with it. I am struggling with my codes, so I want to share it here if someone can help me out as son as possible. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php 

mysql_connect('localhost', '233apps', '233apps');

mysql_select_db('car_sales');

$sql="SELECT * FROM general_reservation";

$records=mysql_query($sql);

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Intellect Group Ltd.</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

<div><nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">IG Homepage</a>

        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->

    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Example row of columns -->
 <div class="row">

    <table width = "1000" border="2" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">

    <tr>
    <th>Car Type</th> 
    <th>Trim</th>
    <th>Year made</th> 
    <th>km</th>
    <th>Exterior Colour</th>
    <th>options</th>
    <th>Cost After Duty </th>
    <th>reserver</th>    
    <tr>

    <?php
echo "<b><center>Minister Database Records</center></b><br><br>";

while($general_reservation=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
    echo "<tr>";
    <span class="field"> <input type="checkbox" name="reservation_id" value="<?php echo $value('reservation_id'); ?>"/> </span>
    echo "<td>".$general_reservation['car_type']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$general_reservation['trim']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$general_reservation['year_made']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$general_reservation['km']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$general_reservation['exterior_colour']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$general_reservation['options']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$general_reservation['car_cost']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$general_reservation['reserver']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
        ?>
     </table>  

        </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: be careful using that mysql_* library: sql injection

Comment: so what do you suggest that I do @DrewPierce ?

Comment: what to do regarding php and sql injection? This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-injection+php?sort=votes&pageSize=50) is for that topic and sorted for you highest vote to lowest.

Comment: Oh and by the way, welcome to The Stack !

Comment: ok, I have seen it. But my conern is adding check box to my table rows @DrewPierce